# Redshift SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger" does not exist

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

every time that I open an SQL script in my Redshift I get the following error:

SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger" does not exist
ERROR: relation "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger" does not exist

I have to mention that my cluster is relatively new.
Does someone know how I can solve it?

Comment: Are you opening it on redshift console in browser or some client you are using like sql-workbench or squirrel to connect with the redshift cluster?

Comment: @NishantGupta I'm using client (DBeaver)

Comment: Can you share the SQL script?

Comment: that's happening for all scripts (even when I open a plain new script) so I assuming it is related to the DB itself